# Get active modal QWidget

Tags: qt, window, modal-dialog

I need to know in my app if a modal window is opened when I click on a button.

So I'm searching for a method which permits to know if a modal window is opened in my application or no, and which returns the window (or NULL)

Is it possible?

Comment: Not that I know of, but if it's your app, don't you know which windows you've set as modal and can simply set a flag that you can test for when they're open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See QApplication's static [activeModalWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#activeModalWidget)